# Android Alarm not firing on time Android version 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-alarms

In my Android application, I need to show notification at some specific time. I a setting the alarm as below, but the notification is not shown on exact time. Instead it is shown at random time after the alarm set time. Below is my code...

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqueCode, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (time != 0) {
        int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentApiVersion <= 18) {
            Log.d(TAG, "API <= 18");
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "I am using Nexus 5 with lollipop and it comes here"); 
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, time, pendingIntent);
        }
```

As I am using Nexus 5 with lollipop, and setting the alarm using setExact() method. Still it is not executing on time...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's name, `setExact` does not trigger an alarm at the exact specified time, for battery saving reasons as far as I know. To really have a precise alarm, use `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock` instead.